# vim syntax: delete a name of a php variable without dollar sign

Tags: vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

In Vim, if I press alt+backspace it will delete the word before the cursor.

With default php.vim syntax it deletes a PHP variable like this:

[image]

What I need to put in a syntax file to make it work like below?

[image]

(I don't mean to install other syntax files with this behavior implemented, I wonder how to control it in my own config.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this snippet to your `vimrc`:

```
augroup PHP
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType php setlocal iskeyword-=$
augroup END
```

See `:help 'iskeyword'`.